# Is there a better way to write a vector of strings as a function's optional parameter?

Tags: c++

I have a function where I want a `const std::vector<std::string>*` parameter to have a default parameter value of `nullptr`:

```
// Definition. Includes a default parameter.
void func(std::vector<std::string>* my_strings = nullptr);

// Call site. Is there a better way?
func(&std::vector<std::string>({"abc"}));
```

Is there a better way to write an optional vector of strings as a parameter?

Comment: A `std::optional<std::vector<std::string>>` maybe?

Comment: What is different between empty and null?

Comment: Consider using `unordered_set` if the order doesn't matter

Comment: It is not legal to take the memory address of a temporary object using the `&` operator, so `func(&std::vector<std::string>({"abc"}));` should not even compile.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It works on MSVC if you use `/permissive`. But yeah, probably don't want to do that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: it would incurs copy though :/ `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<std::string>>>` possibly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `func()` doesn't need to modify the vector, and you don't need to differentiate between "no vector" and "an empty vector", you could do it this way:

```
void func(const std::vector<std::string> & my_strings = std::vector<std::string>());
```

... then you can just call it naturally:

```
func(std::vector<std::string>({"abc"}));
func();
```

Comment: Or `void func(const std::vector<std::string> & my_strings = {});` which is less typing, and equally clear.